# when i try to run this cmd "npm run compile:sass" is show me this error

Tags: javascript, css, npm, sass

Code Git Repo:
https://github.com/TakbeerAli/CssError

'CSS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Takbeer\Courses\node-sass\bin\node-sass'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.16.0
[image: This is my code and cmd image]

Comment: You didn't provide any code. How are we supposed to help you without any code?

Comment: Where is the error in your title in the transcript in the question?

Comment: please check again the Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error in the code. When I move my project folder from the child folder to its parent folder Like ( Disk: C or E ), this solves my problem  and starts working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to install module that you don't have?
Use "npm install package-name" or if you have package-lock.json file in you directory just use "npm ci" command.

If I'm wrong please someone correct me :)

Comment: i have only 1 package  "node-sass " which is already installed i also run "npm ci" but don't worked

this is my Git Repo:
https://github.com/TakbeerAli/CssError

Comment: I cloned your code from github. Used only npm install node-sass and its all working.
Also added '-w' to your script, used it to make compiler watch for any changes, so you won't run this script every time you need to compile sass to css.

P.S Also tried to re-create your error by deleting node-modules folder, but after "npm install" its still all working without any problem.

Comment: On my laptop when I moved my project folder from child folder to its parent folder it start working